# How do I automatically deliver static content using a CDN?

Tags: 7, cdn

I use "Rackspace Cloud Files" service as CDN, which provides a nice API for many CDN-related automation tasks.

How do I integrate Drupal with Rackspace Cloud Files without manually copying static files to the CDN?

Comment: "Your method must work with it.." Whose method? What method? This question has potential, but please improve and clarify it. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @Greg Edited my question. Let me know if there's more confusion..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy

1. Copy the static files to your CDN (Rackspace cloud files in this case)
2. Install http://drupal.org/project/cdn (drupal 7 requires no core patch)
3. Configure the CDN module

Update

You can automate the delivery of content files with the File Conveyor mode, this module integrates with the [File Conveyor daemon](http://fileconveyor.org/). This allows for much more advanced setups: files can be processed (e.g. optimize images like smush.it, minify CSS with YUI Compressor, minify JS with YUI compressor or Google Closure Compiler, before they are synced and your CDN doesn't have to support Origin Pull, any push method is fine (supported transfer protocols: FTP, Amazon S3, Rackspace CloudFiles). File Conveyor is flexible enough to be used with any CDN, thus it enables you to avoid vendor lock-in.

Comment: Nice! But, isn't it a manual method as I need to copy static files manually..

Comment: updated the answer to reflect the file conveyor daemon. This text is also on the drupal CDN module page ;)

Comment: I've found that the whole system (web server) locks up when using the CDN module and File Conveyor when the site receives a lot of traffic. I'm wondering if there is a deadlock when the CDN module is accessing the File Conveyor PID or Synch database.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Cloud Files module](http://drupal.org/project/cloud_files). You can set the file system to Rackspace Cloud Files so that files uploaded to Drupal will be stored and delivered from Rackspace Cloud Files CDN directly (no copying).

Comment: I found that the Cloud Files module didn't work well with Rackspace. I kept getting fatal PHP errors upon saving/updating nodes: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function public_uri() on a non-object in [SITE]/sites/all/modules/cloud_files/rackspacecloudfiles_streams.inc on line 160

Comment: did you make sure that you also installed the php library, like the readme file says?